# Is my High order Component is a good strategy for securing My routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passport.js

I am new to React js,I am using passport js for social Authentication and from server side I am setting cookie.With that cookie I am verifying on client side with wrapping with Hight order Component.This Hoc will specifically check specific value in the decoded cookie for every secure component that is rendering.Is this is a correct way to do it.or Any suggestions

HOC.js

```
import React from 'react';
import jwt from 'jwt-simple';


function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
    class Authentication extends React.Component{
        static contextTypes = {
            router:React.PropTypes.object
        };
        componentWillMount(){
            let specificCookie = readCookie('peace');
            if(specificCookie !== null ){
                let decoded = jwt.decode(token,'NONOE');

                if(decoded.verify !== "falseAlarm"){
                    this.context.router.push('/')

                }
            }else{
                this.context.router.push('/')
            }

        }
        render(){

            return <ComposedComponent {...this.props}/>
        }
    }

    return Authentication
}
```